# HTTP Proxy working normally in browser but doesn't allow connections to any port except 443 in Java

Tags: java, ssl, proxy

I'm experiencing a strange problem that I'm not able to figure out. The proxy when used in my Java code to make non-SSL requests always gives error informing me that I cannot send SSL requests to the specified port (whereas I'm not even trying to send any SSL request), however the same proxy when configured in my Firefox browser works like a charm and I can browse all web sites normally. Note that using the same Java code, I can send requests to 443 port alone. But that's because the proxy detects that the requests are SSL, and that's why it only allows them to pass through 443 port.

I don't have the option to use `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttps.proxyHost` options with me because they simply won't work on the Socket objects, I would need a Socks proxy which I don't have access to. So I opted to go with commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, and used `ProxyClient` object to obtain the socket.

This is the code I'm using to obtain a socket:

```
// Proxy Client
ProxyClient client = new ProxyClient();
client.getHostConfiguration().setHost("google.com", 80);
client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("corporate-proxy", 80);
ConnectResponse response = client.connect();
Socket socket = response.getSocket();
if (socket == null) {
  System.err.println(response.getConnectMethod().getStatusLine());
}
```

and this is the exact error message that is printed by my `System.err.println()` statement:

`HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )`

Please don't suggest me to use `URLConnection` because I don't need the proxy for HTTP requests alone.

I have also tried to explicitly specify the protocol to be `http` without any luck:

`client.getHostConfiguration().setHost("google.com", 80, Protocol.getProtocol("http"));`

Any suggestions on how to configure this `ProxyClient` object, so that the proxy server doesn't see requests to be coming as SSL requests?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I seem to have figured out the reason why the ISA server thought I'm using SSL. Actually the statement `client.connect();` creates a socket that is connected, via the HTTP CONNECT method, to a proxy. The Java doc says that, even though HTTP CONNECT proxying is generally used for HTTPS tunneling, the returned socket will not have been wrapped in an SSL socket.

But for ISA, it would still think about this kind of HTTP request as an SSL request. And when it sees that this SSL request is not on 443, instead it is on some other port, it straight away rejects it.

So now the problem instead is that how do I make the client.connect() call to send an HTTP GET or HTTP HEAD instead of HTTP CONNECT..

Comment: What does the Connection Settings tab in Firefox say the connection is? It looks to me like you need to connect to the proxy on port 443.

Comment: No, I'm not making mistake of using a different port in my Java code than what is configured in my web browser. Please read the update I've just posted; it will automatically rule out all other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but I think this is a limitation os `ISA Server` and not a problem of `ProxyClient`. See the article [here](http://www.isaserver.org/articles/2004tunnelportrange.html) to configure ISA Server to allow to connect to other port, beside 443. I think ISA Server don´t recognize you request because it isnt in a HTTP 1.x request.

Comment: No, as I mentioned in my problem description, when I configure my web browser to use the same proxy, I can open all websites on port 80.

The ISA server is rejecting my request because it thinks that my java code is sending an SSL request on port 80 instead of standard HTTP request.

Comment: I stand correct. If you do a request through ISA server that can ben recognized as a HTTP request, then ISA server will think its a SSL request and will reject it. What exaxtly are you trying to do

Comment: If you do a request through ISA server that can be recognized as HTTP request, the proxy reject it thinking its a SSL request. What are you trying to do exactly? Why you think a `HTTP CONNECT` will solve it but a `HttpClient` can be used? Maybe, you should send some headers just to satisfy ISA Server. Thats the big difference between the java request and the browser request: information passed to ISA Server.

Comment: Yes, after I discovered that my code was doing an HTTP CONNECT, I realized you were right.

Actually, I was trying to have SSH tunneled over HTTP. The server had no way to expose its services as it was protected by a firewall (absolutely no incoming connections on any port), however it could reach internet via a proxy. I had another server which was not behind any firewall which could be used as a middle man. So the protected server would run my code and connect to the middle server using proxy, and the middle server would receive client requests and pass it back to protected server.

Comment: However, as it looks like now, I would have to change my code and convert it to a proper HTTP Servlet on the middle server, and also change the code in my protected server to send proper HTTP GET or POST requests to middle server (instead of HTTP Connect).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Apache HttpClient, your code is different from a similar sample on the Apache web site.  It makes use of some other techniques to make the request, perhaps that's where the difference is.  See the samples [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html), and particularly [this one](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java).

Comment: I agree, the question is somewhat vague, but if https client is needed instead of http client, it is doable in a similar same way.

Comment: The samples link you shared is for HttpClient 4.1.1. I'm using 3.1. Methods are different in 3.1. And the reason I want to use 3.1 is the way it hands me over the socket object. With 4.1.1 examples that you've share I don't see a way to get a socket object without making an actual HTTP request.